# How to get a date and time in Hexidecimal in C

Tags: c, date, time, hex

I need to get the current date and time using C. However, I need it to be in hexadecimal format. Is their a function that returns the timestamp in hex or do I have to get the date and time and convert it to HEX? If so, does anyone have an example for the conversion in C?

Comment: What is wrong with saving the return of `time (NULL)`; in an unsigned value and the printing that in whatever format you choose?

Comment: There is little demand for date/time in hex:)  It's going to be a DIY job, I'm afraid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a pointer to a `tm` structure with `localtime()`, and get the needed values from the fields. Then you can use `sprintf()` to build a time string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t raw_time = time(NULL);
    struct tm *curr = localtime(&raw_time);

    int year = curr->tm_year + 1900;
    int month = curr->tm_mon + 1;
    int day = curr->tm_mday;

    int hour = curr->tm_hour;
    int min = curr->tm_min;
    int sec = curr->tm_sec;

    char time_str[40];
    sprintf(time_str, "%#x/%#x/%#x %#x:%#x:%#x",
            year, month, day, hour, min, sec);

    puts("Hex timestamp:");
    puts(time_str);

    sprintf(time_str, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d",
            year, month, day, hour, min, sec);

    putchar('\n');
    puts("Decimal timestamp:");
    puts(time_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Hex timestamp:
0x7e1/0x3/0x1f 0x14:0x2d:0x28

Decimal timestamp:
2017/3/31 20:45:40
```

Comment: Oh, that's good. Well on the way to the next great fad -- the ***Hex Clock!*** I like the solution.